# What were the demographics of the ancient Crete (any population estimates from 500BCE to 1BCE will do)?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, demography, population

I am looking for any estimates on the population of ancient Crete in the time period 500BCE to 1BCE.
I have searched for such estimates on google but I haven't found anything relevant.

(Note: The prior question asked about *Cyprus*; this question is about *Crete*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What were the demographics of the ancient Greek colonies of Cyprus (any population estimates from 500BCE to 1BCE will do)?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/what-were-the-demographics-of-the-ancient-greek-colonies-of-cyprus-any-populati)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens That was about *Cyprus*. This is about *Crete*. Different islands (although they do both happen to be in the same sea, and both start with a 'C').

Comment: I do have to wonder though what exactly is behind these questions? If we get this answered, can we expect further nearly identical questions about Corsica and Sicily? Will we be here next year answering copies of the same question about Honshu and Sumatra? I'm not sure there's anything wrong with that, but I might need a head's up that I have to pace myself...

Comment: Went and checked, and unfortunately Mr. MeEvedy and Jones aren't as helpful here. They don't have Cretan #'s separated out from the rest of Greece. It looks like they show the territory of modern Greece (including Crete) falling from a bit under 5 million in 500BC to about 4.2 millions in 1AD. How that scales down to just Crete, I'm not sure, but it should at least give you an extreme upper bound. Today Greece has a population of 10 mil, and Crete 0.6 mil, so that would work out to about 0.3 mil back then if it stayed proportional.

Comment: @T.E.D. For Crete it's different. It seems to have slumped after Minoan times, was held back in archaic and classical times, but spurted to max ever population desity in Hellenistic/Early Roman times.